# how do I passing template parameter correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, parameter-passing, rvalue-reference

The following code doesn't compile because `T` is now deduced to be a reference, (either l-value or r-value, but this is not relevant here). So `std::vector` can't take `T` as an argument anymore. Does anyone know some way to fix this? Thanks!

```
template<typename T>
void func( T&& t )
{
    std::vector<T> v;
}
```

Answer: use `std::decay` as commented.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] that produces the issue you are having.

Comment: use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)

Comment: Thank you SirGuy! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

How arguments with deduced types are declared depends on how you plan to use the argument. In the shown declaration you declared the argument as a *forwarding reference* which deduces the template argument depending on how the function is called:

- if the function is called with an lvalue of type `X` the argument `T` will be `X&`
- if the function is called with an rvalue of type `X` the argument `T` will be `X`

The resulting argument is intended to be *forwarded* somewhere and is most likely used using

```
std::forward<T>(t)
```

If you rather consume your argument (i.e., the argument is pit somewhere) you are probably beat off to take it by value (i.e., you'd use `f(T t)`)and `std::move(t)` the value into its final destination. You may want to read the argument but not consume it in which case you should probably pass it as `T const&`.

Assuming the use of a forwarding reference is intentional, you should declare you `std::vector` with a corresponding type obtained from the deduced type, e.g.

```
std::vector<std::decay_t<T>> v;
```